# Pass Parameter into a new window opened from .js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parameters, window

I am planning to update the text box from my website from .js file. Suppose I have a website http://abcd-support. I have a .js file to be executed. What I want to do is, execute my .js file and it will open http://abcd-support and update the value of the textbox. Here is my .js file:

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://abcd-support');
newWindow.onload = function(){
    newWindow.document.getElementById('textbox').value = 'test';
};
```

The new window has opened, however, the textbox (with id 'textbox') in my http://abcd-support is still blank. It should be filled with "test".

Has anyone encountered the same issue before?

Note: **I am using .js file. not HTML file**, **and I am using Google Chrome.**

Comment: Do you want to open the same url in the new window?

Comment: no it is different page. Suppose i am on page A, then I execute .js file to open new window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass value to Child window using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255646/pass-value-to-child-window-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an element with the id `textbox` to assign a value to it.

in this case I understand it's an `input text`

```
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("id", "textbox");
```

tell me if it helped

Comment: the id for the textbox is 'textbox'. it is in my http:/ /abcd-support