# Pass value to Child window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, new-window

I'm attempting to get the `question id` from the parent page and pass it into my new child page. When the child window gets a response it will put this data into `text_body id`. I have managed to create the `question id` and open a new window. However, I get an error when passing the value to `text-body id`.

> Cannot set property 'value' of null.

I think the problem happened because the JavaScript still detect the previous page, and can't focus into the new window. I have included my source code below.

```
function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while(end < start + ms) {
        end = new Date().getTime();
    }
}

var body = document.getElementById('question').innerText;
alert(body);

var k = window.open("http://testing/support");
wait (2000);
k.focus();
wait (1000);
k.focus();
k.document.getElementById('text_body').value = body;
```

Comment: Do a console log of the variable body in the second line and check if it is null

Comment: You need to pass it either as POST or GET, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250766/javascript-sending-custom-parameters-with-window-open-but-its-not-working

Comment: @raspi surya, have you still got issues or has this been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Due to cross-domain restrictions, browsers have clamped down on the security of opening pop-ups and iframes.

The reason you are getting the `Cannot set property 'value' of null` is that you are trying to run the code to open a window directly from javascript - ***without any user action***.

This will prevent the code running correctly, so the `'value'` (property or variable) on `null` (`k` the child window) is your error; `k` is null at the time you are trying to set the variable `'value'`.

Browsers will request permission to allow pop-ups in different ways. If the user hasn't clicked on something to request the pop-up, permission hasn't yet been given to allow it.

The sample code below demonstrates that you will get the error for the initial call to open the `window` and set the child's variable without user action, but when the user clicks on something (the `div` in this case), it will open after confirming permission.

Open the console window, refresh the page and you will see the error for the non-interactive call.

The working parts of the demo use an initial value to display in the `child window`, then after 1.5 seconds, the `parent` will call a function in the `child` that will update the display, and finally, the `parent` will access a `child variable` and set the display directly.

Timers are just for clarity to see the changes as they happen.

Hopefully this covers what you are trying to do...

**parentPage.html:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parent Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divQuestion" onclick="openChild()">Parent text</div>

    <script>
        function openChild() {
            var parentText = document.getElementById("divQuestion").innerText;
            var win = window.open("childPage.html");

            // Call a function in the child window...    
            setTimeout(function () { win.changeValue(parentText) }, 1500);

            // Directly use a variable in the child window...
            setTimeout(function () { win.childText.innerText = body + " and some more..." }, 3000);
        }

        // By calling directly you are attempting to open a child window 
        // without user permission - this will fail.
        // openChild();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**childPage.html:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Child Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="divText">Child text</div>

    <script>
        var childText = document.getElementById("divText");

        function changeValue(val) {
            // Take a value from elsewhere (parent window in this case) and update the div
            childText.innerText = val;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```